# Pixeltransformation with Android

Tags: android, image, graphics, pixel

is there a way to make a pixel transformation in Android by program code, like you see in the pictures below? Source should be the original picture and the result the transformed picture.
It would be very nice if someone could send me the code for it.

I have no idea if it's possible with Android and how I have to programme it.

Thanks for your help

Best regards 
Tom

[image]
Original picture

[image]
Picture after pixel transformation

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution....

```
package com.devcom_networks.graphicslibrary;


import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;

public class Pixelize {
Bitmap originalBmp;
Bitmap obscuredBmp;
Canvas obscuredCanvas ;
Paint obscuredPaint;
private final static int PIXEL_BLOCK = 120;

  public Bitmap createPixelizedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixelsize) 
    {

        if (bitmap == null)
            return null;

        // Create the bitmap that we'll output from this method
        obscuredBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),bitmap.getConfig());

        // Create the canvas to draw on
        obscuredCanvas = new Canvas(obscuredBmp); 
        // Create the paint used to draw with
        obscuredPaint = new Paint();   
        // Create a default matrix
        Matrix obscuredMatrix = new Matrix();       
        // Draw the scaled image on the new bitmap
        obscuredCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, obscuredMatrix, obscuredPaint);


        pixelizeImage(obscuredBmp, obscuredCanvas, pixelsize);

        return obscuredBmp;
    }
private Bitmap pixelizeImage(Bitmap bitmap, Canvas canvas, int pixelSize) 
{

    originalBmp = bitmap;

    if (pixelSize == 0)
        pixelSize = (int)(bitmap.getWidth())/PIXEL_BLOCK;

    if (pixelSize <= 0) //1 is the smallest it can be
        pixelSize = 1;

    int px, py;

    for (int x = 0; x < originalBmp.getWidth() - 1; x+=pixelSize) {
        for (int y = 0; y < originalBmp.getHeight() - 1; y+=pixelSize) {


            px = (x/pixelSize)*pixelSize;
            py = (y/pixelSize)*pixelSize;

            try
            { 
                int pixels[] = new int[pixelSize*pixelSize];
                int newPixel = originalBmp.getPixel(px, py);
                for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
                    pixels[i] = newPixel;

                originalBmp.setPixels(pixels, 0, pixelSize, px, py, pixelSize, pixelSize);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException iae)
            {
                //something is wrong with our pixel math
                break; //stop the filter
            }
        }
    }
    return originalBmp;
}
```

}